# Making any given instance of a CCNode reactive to touch

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

So in my project I am using Cocos2D with CocosBuilder. I have assigned a few of my characters to be subclasses of CCNode with child CCSprites, etc.

I want these CCNodes to be reactive to touch - for example, if I touch any of them, they'd play a context sensitive animation. I only want to know how to make the node reactive to touch (or perhaps, having the layer reactive to touch which detects whether you've touched a sprite or not), the animation part is fine.

Any ideas? that would be lovely.

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this is fairly easy. In the header file of your class, you must define the class as implementing the protocol , like so:

```
@interface Foo : CCNode <CCTouchOneByOneDelegate>
{

}
```

and you must implement onEnter and onExit like this:

```
- (void)onEnter
{
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
    [super onEnter];
}
- (void)onExit
{
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
[super onExit];
}
```

and you must implement ccTouchBegan (if you're using the OneByOneDispatcher)

Comment: Awesome. Never heard of the CCTouchOneByOneDelegate protocol, and it's awesome.

Comment: It's called CCTargetedTouchDelegate now. Still the right thing for the job though!

Comment: Hrm? They changed from CCTargetedTouchDelegate to CCTouchOneByOneDelegate. If you change from Cocos2D pre 2.1 to anythin post you'll notice that CCTargetedTouchDelegate doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, I thought I had the latest Cocos2d since I downloaded the latest stable version a couple weeks ago. Thanks for the info. :)